# How do I remove the line connection between the ellipse? JS Canvas

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to draw a face with Javascript in a canvas and the smile is using `ellipse(x, y, rX, rY, rot, start, end`. I closed the path (`closePath();`) and that follow that with a stroke command (`stroke();`). This draws the ellipse, which looks like a half-circle. But this also draws a stroke which connects the two ends of the half-circle, which I don't want. It looks like this:

```js
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var w = 500;
var h = 300;

window.onload = function() {
  c.style.backgroundColor = '#aaa';
  c.width = w;
  c.height = h;
  c.tabIndex = '1';
  c.style.outline = 'none';
  c.style.display = 'block';
  c.style.margin = '0 auto';
  c.style.position = 'relative';
  c.style.top = '50px';
  document.body.style.margin = '0';
  document.body.appendChild(c);
}

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(w / 2, h / 2, 30, 35, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.fillStyle = '#cf9454';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(w / 2 - 10, h / 2 - 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.moveTo(w / 2 + 10, h / 2 - 10);
  ctx.ellipse(w / 2 + 10, h / 2 - 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(w / 2, h / 2 + 10, 16, 12, 0, 0, 1 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.stroke();
}, 30);
```

[image: Face]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply omit the last `closePath()` call. Its intention is described in [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/closePath):

> The `CanvasRenderingContext2D.closePath()` method of the Canvas 2D API attempts to add a straight line from the current point to the start of the current sub-path.

It effectively adds that straight line to the "mouth" shape. So just leave that out:

```js
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var w = 500;
var h = 140; // reduced to make the smiley appear within the snippet area

window.onload = function() {
  c.width = w;
  c.height = h;
  c.tabIndex = '1';
  c.style.backgroundColor = '#aaa';
  c.style.outline = 'none';
  c.style.display = 'block';
  c.style.margin = '0 auto';
  c.style.position = 'relative';
  c.style.top = '50px';
  document.body.style.margin = '0';
  document.body.appendChild(c);
}

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(w / 2, h / 2, 30, 35, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.fillStyle = '#cf9454';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(w / 2 - 10, h / 2 - 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.moveTo(w / 2 + 10, h / 2 - 10);
  ctx.ellipse(w / 2 + 10, h / 2 - 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(w / 2, h / 2 + 10, 16, 12, 0, 0, 1 * Math.PI);
  //ctx.closePath(); //<----- remove this

  ctx.stroke();
}, 30);
```

Note that Unicode has characters for smileys. Maybe they are useful for your project? I would also move some of the styling to CSS definitions. The `setInterval` is currently useless; but I suppose you have it for future purposes.

For example:

```js
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var w = 500;
var h = 140; // reduced to make the smiley appear within the snippet area

window.onload = function() {
  c.width = w;
  c.height = h;
  c.tabIndex = 1;
  document.body.appendChild(c);
  ctx.font = "70px Verdana";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle"; 
  setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.fillText("", w/2, h/2);
  }, 30);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #aaa;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
body { margin: 0; }
```